# Configuring error with Buildroot

Tags: raspberry-pi3, configure, buildroot

I am working on a project for Raspberry Pi 3 and i'm using buildroot for building linux kernel, fs etc. But every now and then (when i change the settings of buildroot for example) i am no longer able to successfully finish the build proccess even if i roll back to previous configuration (even if i choose initial raspberrypi3_defconfig configuration). The error is always similar:

> > > host-binutils 2.28.1 Configuring
> > >       (cd /home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/build/host-binutils-2.28.1/ && rm -rf config.cache; PATH="/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/bin:/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/sbin:/home/andy/bin:/home/andy/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" PKG_CONFIG="/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/bin/pkg-config" PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="/" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR="/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/lib/pkgconfig:/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/share/pkgconfig" AR="/usr/bin/ar" AS="/usr/bin/as" LD="/usr/bin/ld" NM="/usr/bin/nm" CC="/usr/bin/gcc" GCC="/usr/bin/gcc" CXX="/usr/bin/g++" CPP="/usr/bin/cpp" OBJCOPY="/usr/bin/objcopy" RANLIB="/usr/bin/ranlib" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/include" CFLAGS="-O2 -I/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/include" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -I/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/lib" INTLTOOL_PERL=/usr/bin/perl CFLAGS="-O2 -I/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/include" LDFLAGS="-L/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/lib" MAKEINFO=true CONFIG_SITE=/dev/null ./configure --prefix="/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host" --sysconfdir="/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/etc" --localstatedir="/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/var" --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc --disable-gtk-doc-html --disable-doc --disable-docs --disable-documentation --disable-debug --with-xmlto=no --with-fop=no --disable-dependency-tracking  --disable-multilib --disable-werror --target=-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf --disable-shared --enable-static --with-sysroot=/home/andy/embedded_linux/buildroot/output/host/-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf/sysroot --enable-poison-system-directories --disable-sim --disable-gdb  )
> > >       configure: loading site script /dev/null
> > >       checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> > >       checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
> > >       checking target system type... configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub -buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf failed

The error can occur while configuring some other utility (for example while configuring flex 2.6.4, or dropbear etc) but the main parttern  of the error is always the same:
checking target system type... configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub -buildroot-linux-something failed

Couldn't find out the solution to that problem, please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly get what is going wrong, but as you describe "when i change the settings of buildroot for example", I can tell you that buildroot has no means of supporting this in all cases from a normal `make`. You should e.g. use a `make clean` and do a full rebuild.

See [https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild%20Buildroot%20Manual%20-%20Full%20rebuild) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but the thing is that even if i do make clean all (full rebuild) i get the same error:                                                                                    
>>> host-binutils 2.28.1 Configuring
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub -buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf failed